# Do critical hit spirits also stack with Hero's passive of having a chance to crit on f. smash?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

Just curious if critical hit spirits (eg. Blade Lord Lyn, Mythra) stack additively/multiplicatively with Hero's passive chance to perform a critical hit on an F.Smash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you would be *technically* correct to say that spirit crits and Hero smash crits "stack multiplicatively". But it would be more correct to say that they are entirely separate mechanics that do not directly interact with each other:

- Spirit crits give a percent chance (5% or 12%) for any attack's damage to be multiplied.
- Hero's smash crits give a percent chance (12.5%) for his smash attacks to use a different set of hitboxes that deal more damage to enemies and have other minor attribute differences.

Comment: +1 for specifying the difference between the two. Hero's crit's are more than just a damage multiplier.